# Performance Issue with heic2any.js as static resource in Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, performance, salesforce-lightning, staticresource, heic

I am trying to render HEIC files in the browser by converting them to JPEG using the heic2any.min.js library. While using the library in vanilla JavaScript, the conversion process takes only a few seconds for a 1MB HEIC image. However, when I uploaded the library as a static resource and used it in a Salesforce Lightning Web Component (LWC), the conversion time for the same image exceeds 5 minutes. I am looking for insights into the potential reasons behind this significant performance difference.

I have experimented with several JavaScript libraries for converting HEIC images to JPEG/PNG formats, but all of them seem to have similar performance issues. My goal is to optimize the execution time of the heic2any function or understand why the conversion process takes significantly longer than expected. Any insights or suggestions to enhance the performance of the conversion would be highly appreciated.